# Error A local variable cannot be declared in this scope

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am trying to unzip a file with DotNetZip but I get a error on the "e"

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(openFileDialog1.FileName))
{
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
    {
        e.Extract(Environment.CurrentDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: You're lacking context. Please give the full method. There probably will be another local variable or parameter with the name `e`. The `EventArgs` parameter on eventhandlers is often called `e`.

Comment: C# does not allow the same "simple name" to be used twice in the same block to mean two different things. Somewhere in this method you use "e" to mean something else. Change one of them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect you are doing this inside an event handler which already has a parameter called `e`.

Try renaming `e` to `entry` inside the `foreach`.